# Laravel error : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

I have a trouble when trying to add or update data in a table (siswa) that has one-to-one relation with other table (telepon), when I submit the data (adding/updating)I keep getting this error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' nomor_telepon' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `telepon` where `nomor_telepon` = 081255758609).

Here's table siswa migration code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableSiswa extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('siswa', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nisn',4)->unique();
            $table->string('nama_siswa',50);
            $table->date('tanggal_lahir');
            $table->enum('jenis_kelamin',['L','P']);
            $table->integer('id_kelas')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('siswa');
    }
}
```

Table telepon migration code :

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableTelepon extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('telepon', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_siswa')->unsigned();
            $table->primary('id_siswa');
            $table->foreign('id_siswa')
                    ->references('id')->on('siswa')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');

            $table->string('nomor_telepon')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();


        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('telepon');
    }
}
```

Model Siswa code :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Siswa extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'siswa';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nisn',
        'nama_siswa',
        'tanggal_lahir',
        'jenis_kelamin'
    ];

    protected $dates = ['tanggal_lahir'];

    public function getNamaSiswaAttribute($nama_siswa) 
    {
        return ucwords($nama_siswa);
    }

    public function telepon()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Telepon', 'id_siswa');
    }

    public function kelas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kelas', 'id_kelas');
    }
}
```

Model telepon code :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Telepon extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'telepon';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_siswa';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_siswa',
        'nomor_telepon',
    ];

    public function siswa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Siswa', 'id_siswa');
    }
}
```

And here's my add and update data method :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'nisn' => 'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn',
            'nama_siswa' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'tanggal_lahir' => 'required|date',
            'jenis_kelamin' => 'required|in:L,P',
            'nomor_telepon' => 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:telepon, nomor_telepon',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('siswa/create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $siswa = Siswa::create($input);

        $telepon = new Telepon;
        $telepon->nomor_telepon = $request->input('nomor_telepon');
        $siswa->telepon()->save($telepon);

        return redirect('siswa');
    }

public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $siswa = Siswa::findOrFail($id);
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'nisn' => 'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn,' . $request->input('id'),
            'nama_siswa' => 'required|string|max:50',
            'tanggal_lahir' => 'required|date',
            'jenis_kelamin' => 'required|in:L,P',
            'nomor_telepon' => 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:telepon, nomor_telepon,' . 
            $request->input('id') . ',id_siswa',
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('siswa/' . $id . '/edit')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
        $siswa->update($request->all());

        $telepon = $siswa->telepon;
        $telepon->nomor_telepon = $request->input('nomor_telepon');
        $siswa->telepon()->save($telepon);
        return redirect('siswa');
    }
```

Comment: I am new to php framework and still learning but I'm stuck at this error, so please help me :) thankyou

Comment: Check actual DB. Does `telepon` table has `nomor_telepon` column? If not, did you see any error messages when you ran `migrate` command?

Comment: yes telepon table has nomor_telepon column. No I didnt see any error when I executed the migrate command @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: It seems `'nomor_telepon' => 'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:telepon, nomor_telepon'` causes the error. Do you use multiple connections in your app? Try maybe to add connection name to the rule, like `...|unique:mysql.telepon,nomor_telepon` (if connection name is `mysql`)

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by multiple connections ? But maybe it can help if I explain what I wanted in my app, here is it : Table Siswa (Siswa = student in English ) contains student data, and telepon (phone) table contains phone number (nomor_telepon column = phone_number) data. What I want is that each student can only have ONE phone number. I separated phone number data from student data because I wanted to learn how to use relations in laravel :) @AlexeyMezenin

Comment: Ok, I guess you're using single connection. Did you try code from my previous comment? Also, try this one: `...|unique:telepon'`

Comment: The first one did not working, but the second one works! Thankyou so much!! @AlexeyMezenin